# Using JFileChooser in XSSFWorkbook getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed

Tags: java

Choosing the file using JFileChooser and trying to read it by XSSFWorkbook but i am encountering the error as  java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed.

Below is my code where i am getting error. Please help me in resolving.

```
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(  "xlsx", "xlsx");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(getParent());
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
           System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " +
                chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());

        //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
        String filename=chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
        // getting  java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(filename); 

        int numberOfSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSheets; i++) {
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
        System.out.println("numberOfSheets :"+numberOfSheets);
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the complete filename, including the path:

Instead of

```
String filename=chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
```

use

```
String filename = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: i tried chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath() but i am getting error saying the method getAbsolutePath() is undefined for the type String

Comment: The message is weird, because getSelectedFile() returns a File, not a String.
Did you perhaps accidentally write `chooser.getSelectedFile().getName().getAbsolutePath()` or something similar.